# Directive function parameter is undefined

Tags: angularjs

Directive Template URL:

```
<div class="filter-input" ng-click="changeVisualization('trocaparaeste')">
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('asideFilter', function() {
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    categories: "=",
    change: "&onChange",
    changeVisualization: '&onChangeVisualization'

  },
  templateUrl: 'assets/directives/asideFilter/asideFilter.html',
  controller: function($scope){
  }
 };
});;
```

Directive usage:

```
<aside-filter change-visualization="onChangeVisualization()"/>
```

Controller that im trying to get the parameter data:

```
  $scope.onChangeVisualization = function(option) {
   console.log('option', option);
  }
```

SOLUTION:

Directive Template URL:

```
<aside-filter on-change-visualization="onChangeVisualization(option)"/>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('asideFilter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        categories: "=",
        change: "&onChange",
        changeVisualization: '&onChangeVisualization'

    },
    templateUrl: 'assets/directives/asideFilter/asideFilter.html',
    link: function(scope){
      // pass 'option' variable so it can be used in the callback
      scope.changeVisualization({ option: "worked!" });
    }
  };
});;
```

Directive usage:

```
<aside-filter change-visualization="onChangeVisualization(option)"/>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry. My question is, why in my parent controller, where im trying to console the data, its being undefined?

Comment: Because you don't pass any data in `change-visualization="onChangeVisualization()"`

Answer (score 2):

You have your names switched:

```
scope: {
    // prefixed with 'on'
    // so usage: <my-directive on-change-visualization="someFunc(option)"/>
    changeVisualization: '&onChangeVisualization'
},
// example:
link: function($scope) {
    scope.changeVisualization = scope.changeVisualization || angular.noop;

    // pass 'option' variable so it can be used in the callback
    scope.changeVisualization({ option: "worked!" });
}
```

And change your html to:

```
<!-- with the prefixed 'on-' -->
<aside-filter on-change-visualization="onChangeVisualization(option)" />
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.onChangeVisualization = function(option) {
    console.log('option', option); // logs: 'option worked!'
}
```

Comment: OK, some progress, but how i can get the data that ive passed by args in ng-click ? in Directive Template URL

Comment: thanks man! I was missing to pass the object by parameter when calling it by ng-click!